# Providing counterexamples for a false statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B, C$ be three sets so that the family $\{A, B, C\}$ is disjoint. Then at least one of $A \cap B, B \cap C, A \cap C$ has no element.

Since they are disjoint sets, shouldnt the sets have no common intersection, which would make this sentence true?

Comment: "family ... is disjoint" suposedly means only $A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset$. Try $\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\}$.

Comment: Saying that the family is disjoint usually just means that there is no element in all three.  Not that they are pairwise disjoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always good to be careful with definitions.

A standard definition for "disjoint family" is:

> A family of sets $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is disjoint if $$\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i=\emptyset$$

---

So, following the standard definition, your statement says:

> If $A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset$, then at least one of $A\cap B, B\cap C$ or $A\cap C$ has no element.

This statement is not true, and a simple counterexample can show it is not.

Answer (score 2):

If a family of sets, here $\{A, B, C\}, $ are disjoint, we know only that $A\cap B \cap C = \varnothing$

This is different than saying that a family of sets is **pairwise disjoint**, in which $A\cap B =\varnothing, B\cap C = \varnothing, A\cap C = \varnothing.$

Claim: Let $A, B, C$ be three sets so that the family $\{A, B, C\}$ is disjoint, i.e. $A\cap B\cap C = \varnothing)$.
 Then at least one of $A \cap B, B \cap C, A \cap C$ has no element.

In this case, a counterexample to the claim you post is $$A = \{1, 2\}, B = \{2, 3\}, C = \{1, 3\}$$